# How to divide ASCII code in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So in Powershell I am trying to take the Ascii values of a file and divide them by a value. I have what I want to happen shown below, I have NO idea how to do this.

$value would be 300
$file would be $home\test.txt

So what I want it to do is get the content of the file in Ascii code format, so lets pretend that the file says "Hello". When you get the content it will be this:

```
72
101
108
108
111
```

What I really want it to do is take all of the Ascii values ok, then put them all together in one line. So Hello which is:

```
72
101
108
108
111
```

Would become:

```
72101108108111
```

And I would then take the number shown above and divide it by $value and the ending result would be set as the content of the file. The only way to decrypt it would then be to multiply that number by the correct key, then split it up again into the normal Ascii format:

```
72
101
108
108
111
```

I then want the script to take the values shown above and put them into 1 line so it would then appear like this:

```
72101108108111
```

I would then take that and divide it by $value and get this:

```
240337027027.037
```

And what is shown above would then be the content set to the file. Now to decrypt it you would take the contents of the file (Which would now be 240337027027.037) and multiply it by the same value as you used to divide it earlier and if done right you should get this:

```
72101108108111
```

And then that would be seperated into the original Ascii values of this:

```
72
101
108
108
111
```

And then that would be set as the content of the file in -encoding byte again to get the original content back of the file. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I don't know what dividing ASCII code means. You should show an example of input and what you expect for the output.

Comment: I will do that right now :) Sorry I don't know what it's exactly called.

Comment: I think he knows what ASCII is, but what do you mean by dividing it? Would you want it to become 72/$value 101/$value ..... ? or (72 101 108 108 111) / $value ?

Comment: I would **strongly** advise against trying to roll your own encryption algorithm. If you want to encrypt something, use the methods/objects from the [`System.Security.Cryptography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) namespace, e.g. [`AESManaged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx).

Comment: You should show your expected output, as I said before. It sounds like you want to read in the file as a large integer (*not* ASCII) and divide it by another large integer. So `Hello` might be 310,939,249,775. But `32984729847569237498` is larger, so integer division by that number will just give you 0.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like this?

```
#Set value (I had to set a lower value because your value was way too large to process with a Int32 (and 64 I think)
$value = 22949672

#Convert (had to multiply because dividing casues to small number to be save correctly(it rounds up and ruins the decoding later)
Get-Content .\test.txt -Encoding Byte | % { $_ * $value } | Set-Content .\test2.txt -Encoding Ascii

#Convert back
Get-Content .\test2.txt -Encoding Ascii | % { [byte]($_ / $value) } | Set-Content .\test3.txt -Encoding Byte
```